# Selenium and beautiful soup unable to find video tag tag on webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need a web scraping experts help. Im trying to get the src from the video tag of this website. When I try to use selenium or beautifulsoup4 to catch it, its as if doesnt exist. find_elements returns an empty list. This "//*[@id="player"]/div[2]/div[3]/video" is the XPATH for that element from inspect elements in safari. I can see it while inspecting the webpage but I cannot scrape it. Ive also tried using the find_element("src") method to no success. It throws an exception saying no such element found.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    # Navigate to Url
driver.get("https://anime47.com/xem-phim-chainsaw-man-ep-01/187898.html")

    # Get all the elements available with tag name 'p'
elements = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")

for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: What exactly do you need? Your question is different from the code you've posted, post the question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The element can be found using this code:

```
video = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="player"]/div[2]/div[3]/video')
```

But this element doesn't have the `src` attribute, so you will not be able to get it from the element. And looks like there is no possibility to get the video from this page.